# C# Efficient image drawing and moving

Tags: c#, graphics

So I'm making a side scrolling game using tiled images. At any given time there's at least ~120 images being drawn using this code:

```
for (int mapX = 0; mapX < mapWidth; mapX++)
{
    for (int mapY = 0; mapY < mapHeight; mapY++)
    {
        try
        {
            Block block = mapList[mapY, mapX];

            if (block == null)
                continue;

            if (block.nullspace)
                continue;

            block.Interact();

            int drawX = sceneX + block.blockX;
            int drawY = sceneY + block.blockY;

            if (drawX + block.blockWidth < 0)
                continue;
            else if (drawX > this.ClientSize.Width + 50)
                break;

            if (drawY + block.blockHeight < 0)
                continue;
            else if (drawY > this.ClientSize.Height)
                break;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(block.blockImage, drawX, drawY, block.blockWidth, block.blockHeight);

            if (block.overlayImage != null && !block.dontDraw)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(block.overlayImage, sceneX + block.blockX, sceneY + block.blockY, block.blockWidth, block.blockHeight);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However this code is being run every single time an image needs to be moved. For example, to get the entire scene to move, I have a timer with an interval of 10 (To keep movement smooth) which will decrement sceneX (Since I'm moving the scene to the left) and then it's repainting the entire scene. So essentially, ~120 images are being repainted every 10 ticks. This is causing my program to reach about 40% CPU usage on my computer.

Basically my question is: "What is the most efficient way of drawing and moving lots of image tiles"

Here's an image of the scene being drawn:
[image: An image of the scene]

Comment: Don't tell me you're making a game in windows forms...

Comment: @animaonline It's not a serious game, just a little project to learn C# a little better. Would you suggest a better method of doing such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

You're simply overloading your CPU, because the graphics are rendered in software mode.

Use MonoGame, it is really simple to get started with, it handles the drawing for you https://github.com/mono/MonoGame and learn a bit about game mechanics here: http://xnagpa.net/xna4rpg.php

MonoGame supports both Direct3D and OpenGL, the graphics are hardware accelerated, and you won't notice a slowdown when rendering a simple 2D scene.

Comment: Are you sure it's the rendering that's causing the CPU usage? He's doing a lot of unnecessary processing just to figure out what needs to be drawn.

Comment: It may be the code, but either way,  windows forms is not hardware accelerated, so rendering will most likely be done by the cpu.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is determine what range of your map is visible on the screen. Right now, you have:

```
for (int mapX = 0; mapX < mapWidth; mapX++)
{
    for (int mapY = 0; mapY < mapHeight; mapY++)
```

So you're running the loop for the entire world to see if each individual square is visible. You can reduce the amount of work by determining the limits prior to the loop. That way, you limit your loop to:

```
for (int mapx = startVisibleX; mapX <= endVisibleX; mapX++)
{
    for (int mapY = startVisibleY; mapY <= endVisibleY; mapY++)
```

If your world is much larger than your screen, that's going to save you a lot of needless processing.

If the speed of rendering becomes an issue, I strongly suggest that you heed the advice in the other answers and look into DirectX, MonoGame, or another rendering library.

Comment: Yep.  I was looking at this from a different standpoint, but this is a good point, and brings up a golden rule of game programming...don't do more computation than you have to.

Answer (score 1):

[XNA.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714) If you're at this stage in Windows Forms, you won't find using the Microsoft XNA libraries much different, and your results will be better, since they'll take advantage of DirectX, hardware acceleration, etc. without you having to worry about it. (And your code will be faster, and more natural to read/write, since XNA is designed for games/graphics...stuff like this is one of the goals of XNA.)

XNA is a very natural fit for learning C# (since it was created by Microsoft), it plays very nicely with Visual Studio, it's free, and there are tons of tutorials online.

Comment: XNA is dead, Microsoft will not provide support for XNA stating 2014,MonoGame on the other hand is fully XNA compatible, and is an actively developed open source project.

Comment: @animaonline He said himself that it's not a "serious" game...he's doing this to learn C#. It seems like it's not a problem to me if XNA isn't going to get additional support/updates in another year. I would lean towards XNA, because I happen to know it integrates easily and seamlessly...whereas integrating an open source project may be a different kind of hurdle to overcome. One  that is being "actively developed" is perhaps not finished, may have unimplemented features, etc.  It's probably not a bad choice, but I'd still look towards XNA, and move towards MonoGame, if necessary, later.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should have a look at using DirectX for rendering purposes. This is best practice when developing game under Windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452790.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Consider using **TranslateTransform** to move images over surface. This should give some boost to performance.